# Function not defined when adding javascript (codepen) to my Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add this code to my Rails 5 app: https://codepen.io/marklocklear/pen/jjGLRx

I created a file called stopwatch.js in app/assets/javascripts and put the JS code wrapped in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...JS code from codepen
});
```

When I click the Start Button in my Rails app I get the console message:

```
edit:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: startWatch is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (edit:63)
```

Also, in application.js I have:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code executed from HTML attributes is executed in the global scope. if you put the code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...JS code from codepen
});
```

then the functions are declared in the scope of that function, not the global scope.

There's no need to put function definitions inside `$(document).ready`. You only have to put code that shouldn't run until the DOM is loaded. Functions aren't run until they're called, and that won't happen until the user clicks on elements, which obviously can't happen before the DOM is loaded and displayed.

However, your functions reference variables that are declared in the `$(document).ready` function, so you'll run into another scoping problem if you move the functions outside. So the solution for this is to keep the function definitions inside, but have them create global function names. Change

```
function stopWatch() {
  ...
}
```

to

```
window.stopWatch = function() {
  ...
};
```

Another solution is to get rid of the `onclick` attributes in the HTML, and use jQuery event binding.

```
$("#start").click(startWatch);
$("#reset").click(resetWatch);
```